# how do make the bg color of text in css span the whole screen in width

Tags: html, css

I am starting out with html and css and want to know how to give a line of text a background-color. For example :

```css
#python-heading {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 600px;
    left: 600px;
    background-color: #DEE0D9;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <header>
            <span><h1 id="python-heading">Python</h1></span>
            <h2 id="python-subheading">Subtitle</h2>
        </header>
</body>
```

but my text not the whole area behind the text. i mean that i want it like this:

hyphen => bg color

-------------------------------------------text--------------------------------------------------------

but it is like this:

```
                                      -text-
```

what do i need to change/add?

Comment: Dear @Ght007 Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve :) I could get it fully ... In your HTML There us <h1 id="python-heading">Python</h1> Python as Text right and you want dashes like -----Python----- Why CSS? Is this you question friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should avoid using `h1` inside `span` and simply go with `h1` and following code change. ( If I have understood your question correctly then this may help)

```css
#python-heading {
    background-color: #DEE0D9;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1 id="python-heading">Python</h1>
 <h2 id="python-subheading">Subtitle</h2>
</header>
```

Comment: yes that is what i want but i end up with a strange gap between heading and subheading. how do i make it so the gap as well is filled with the color/. the other answer would solve that problem. wouldn't it? i mean it makes use of the px positioning where one positions it themselves

Comment: That's the default margin on the heading elements in HTML you simply have to use h1,h2{ margin-bottom:0;} Note that  **span is an inline-element and h1 a block-level element** Don't use h1 inside span :) It's not recommended my Friend

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:100%;` and change `left:600px;` to `padding-left:600px;`

```css
#python-heading {
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 600px;
    left:0;
    padding-left: 600px;
    background-color: #DEE0D9;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <header>
            <span><h1 id="python-heading">Python</h1></span>
            <h2 id="python-subheading">Subtitle</h2>
        </header>
</body>
```